# My computer is frustratingly slow

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I've done all the basic checks, virus scanning, disc space, back ground processes and there seems nothing out of the ordinary. My browser has at least 5 second response delay minimum and just everything I click my pc will just crash or take forever to load.
Specs: 
Windows XP - 64bit
Processor: Intel Core, 2quad CPU
RAM: 8GB
HDD: Hitachi HD ATA

Comment: @dual operating system?have you checked disk for errors?does your registry  defraged?open msconfig from command prompt and check for startupservices,and inetmgr to check current services running in background which cant be viewed in taskmanager

Comment: Which processor?  the Q6400?  Q6600?  Q6700?  Which Browser?  IE?  Firefox?  Chrome?  Is it a special 64 bit build of Firefox?  What size Hitachi drive?  SATA or PATA?  How old it is?  How many tabs do you have trying to open at once in your browser when you open it?  What else do you have running?  Do you have any toolbars installed?  have you tried another browser?  Have you scanned for MALWARE and SPYWARE as they are not covered by most (if not all) Anti-Virus protection?  What else is slow?  Details... these are the details we need.

Comment: which antivirus program you have? sometimes antivirus programs uses too many of resources. If you running windows then use Microsoft Security Essential.

Answer (score 2):

Problem may with your registry or the file system. Try to clean your registry and then defragment it. Your file system may also get fragmented. So defragment your hard drive.
Remove all the broken shortcut, this may aslo slowdown your computer. For all that issues you can use [Tuneup Utilities](http://www.tune-up.com/download/).
You have lots of program that has not been uninstalled correctly, remove that programs with [Innovative Uninstaller Pro](http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-Uninstaller-Pro/3000-2096_4-10069986.html)

**Other important things are**  :
    Make sure you have all the latest Windows updates installed in the computer.
    If you are on the Internet when your computer is slow also make sure all browser plugins are up-to-date.

Make sure you've got the latest drivers for your computer. Especially the latest video drivers. Having out-of-date drivers can cause an assortment of issues.

Make sure your computer and processor is not overheating, excessive heat can cause a significant decrease in computer performance some processors will even lower the speed of the processor automatically to help compensate for the heat related issues.

Comment: Registry cleaning can't solve this problem or any other.

Comment: But defragmenting hard drive actually can - I saw that once

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause of the hard disk slow down is the PIO mode enable instead of DMA mode:

Check this MSKB article [IDE ATA and ATAPI disks use PIO mode after multiple time-out or CRC errors occur](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817472)

A link for an Hotfix is available from this page

More info about DMA/PIO there: [DMA reverts to PIO](http://winhlp.com/node/10)

Answer (score 1):

### Check CPU usage

Use Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), select the Processes tab and click the CPU column header to sort processes by descending CPU usage. If there is a process (other than "idle") that is using most of your CPU, most of the time, you can stop that process or prevent it from loading at startup.

### Anti-Virus

In some cases, anti-virus products can conflict with other software. Microsoft's Security Essentials occasional does so (look for "msmpeng" in task manager). You may be able to observe this using Task Manager. If so you can try temporarily disabling other startup processes one at a time and rebooting until the conflicting program becomes obvious.

### Startup programs

Use the Start icon to run or search for "msconfig", this lists startup items and allows you to disable them. This can be useful for identifying programs that cause problems.

### Worst case

Backup your data, check you can read all your backups, reinstall Windows, restore data.